# Angular ngClass Not Evaluating to Class Names

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, class

I am trying to create a custom class name using ng-class. I want to combine the values of two scope variables to create that name. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <div ng-class="{quarter+number}">This should have a class of '.quarter12'</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
]);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 
    function($scope, $filter, $http){
      $scope.quarter = 'quarter';
      $scope.number = 12;

    }]);
```

Also see codepen: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/NqGzBM

When the page loads, the div element should have a class of '.quarter12', because of the corresponding variable values in the controller. However, instead, it throws an error. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-class` expects `expression` not `string` you could fulfil your requirement using class with interpolation directive.

```
<div class="{{quarter+number}}">This shoul have a class of '.quarter12'</div>
```

**Update**

More better and convenient solution to set attribute value is by using `ng-attr` directive. `ng-attr` create and attribute with evaluated value of `{{}}` interpolation.

```
<div ng-attr-class="{{quarter+number}}">This shoul have a class of '.quarter12'</div>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbmPpz)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead:

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="getClassName()">This should have a class of '.quarter12'</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $filter, $http){
         $scope.quarter = 'quarter';
         $scope.number = 12;

         $scope.getClassName = function() {
             retrun $scope.quarter + $scope.number;
         }
    }]);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqPdmY

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but if you were to **console.log()** from within the ```$scope.getClassName``` function, you'd see that it gets called for every $digest on the page.